# Updating NPM on OpenShift

Tags: openshift

Is it possible to update NPM to the latest version in an OpenShift application? (It comes with version 1.2.17 by default and I'm trying to upgrade to 1.4.x)

Running the usual NPM command `npm update npm -g` returns a permission error;

`Error: EACCES, unlink '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'`

And running `sudo npm update npm -g` gives a permission denied (`bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied`)

Comment: Any more error data? You can try to check you home directory if folders `tmp` and other npm folders there are actually owned by you. if not, then chown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tips on how to add your own globally installed npm mods to OpenShift might work for this purpose - https://gist.github.com/ryanj/9751652

I haven't tried using this script to update npm itself, but it could be worth a shot.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: No luck with that script unfortunately. However, I saw [the answer you posted on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788457/how-to-update-npm-on-an-openshift-gear/22791994#22791994) and was able to solve this using [nodejs-custom-version-openshift](https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift).

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the proper permissions, you might also want to remove nodejs and retry to install but before that try doing:

```
sudo chmod +x $(which node)
```

or

```
sudo chmod 755 $(which node) && sudo npm update npm -g
```

Also as for the first error it seems you have a permission error on your home directories NPM folders. Try to check if everything in your home dir is owned by you.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is more of a openshift problem than NPM. Openshift seems to block the `sudo` command, so I can't change the permissions on anything.